# Weblogic Leaked Connection timeout

Tags: java, connection, weblogic

If the database query call made using the connection obtained from the Weblogic datasource, never returns within the connection inactive timeout, will it cause connection leak.
for example, the connection inactive timeout is 500 seconds and the DB call takes 600 seconds to return

Will it cause connection leak ?

Answer (score 0):

When your query takes more time than it is defined in connection transaction properties, then SQLException will occur (TransactionTimeout) and your execution will be aborted. If you have too many such concurrent queries, it may result in bad weblogic state and you would need to restart application server (maybe datasource restart would be sufficient).

Comment: In this case I am setting the connection inactive timeout property of weblogic. Let's say connection transaction property is untouched or may be more than the inactive timeout property (it may be the wrong practice or not), but basically i just want to understand how the inactive timeout property behaves. Is it like, the moment the connection gets released from the pool, will it start counting for 500 seconds or how will it be..?

Comment: The documentation claims: The number of inactive seconds on a reserved connection before WebLogic Server reclaims the connection and releases it back into the connection pool.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigconnectionpooltitle.html
I understand it, that once you start some query, deduction will start and if your query does not return meanwhile, execution will be interrupted.

Comment: Thanks Leos. Yeah, I understand it from the documentation, but that is what i am not quite sure about :(

Comment: Try to simulate it. Write some PL/SQL procedure using dbms_lock.sleep(no_of_seconds) which is substantially bigger than inactive timeout property in datasource. Then call this procedure from ejb. I recently wrote blog at www.literak.cz that executes db function so you can inspire there.